# I am trying to center my grid of projects but there is margin, or extra space that i can get rid of to the right of the page. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4, grid

In my project section for my portfolio site all the sections are responsive, but my project section is off on larger screen sizes and there is extra space to the right Ive tried removing margins but it is still there how can I remove this and center the container?

[here is the problem in my dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEo37.png)

```css
#projects {
  text-align: center;
}

#projects .grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#projects .grid .container {
  text-align: center;
}

#projects .container {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#projects .container .box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#projects .container .box:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(1.25);
  box-shadow: 0 25px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#projects .container .box .imgbx {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#projects .container .box .imgbx:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1a75ff, #000);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#projects .container .box:hover .imgbx:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

#projects .container .box .imgbx img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#projects .container .box .box-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#projects .container .box .box-content h3 {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: translateY(200px);
}

#projects .container .box:hover .box-content h3 {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

#projects .container .box .box-content p {
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(200px);
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#projects .container .box:hover .box-content p {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<section id="projects">

  <h2 class="content-title">Recent Work</h2>
  <div class="grid container">

    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img class="projectImg" src="project-images/gadue.png" id="img1" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div>
          <h3>Gadue</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, blanditiis?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img class="projectImg" src="project-images/myherohome.png" id="img2" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div>
          <h3>My Hero Wiki</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, natus.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img src="project-images/stockapphome.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div>
          <h3>TheStockApp</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, aspernatur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img class="projectImg" src="project-images/blackjack.png" id="img4" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div>
          <h3>blackjack game</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, fuga.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: try container-fluid instead of container

Answer (score 0):

Why you doesnt use the grid from bootstrap ? You can fix this with that. Or you can try to give your grid container a margin like this

```
#projects .grid{
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I fixed it I had a brain freeze moment I mixed up my regular css and my media queries, thank you for the help.